# Symfony2 ManytoMany relation with nullable true

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to use an optional ManyToMany relation between Ordo_soins_perfusion and Ordo_soins_medicament entities.

```
  class Ordo_soins_perfusion
  {

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ordo_soins_medicament",cascade={"persist"})
  *@ORM\JoinTable(name="ordo_soinperf_soinmedoc",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Ordo_soins_perfusion_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Ordo_soins_medicament_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)})
 */
private $medoc;

    class Ordo_soins_medicament
    {
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="medicament", type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
 */
private $medicament;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="quantite", type="string", length=50,nullable=true)
 */
private $quantite;
```

Now when i save a new Ordo_soins_perfusion object without filling the Ordo_soins_medicament form i found a new ligne created in the join table and in the Ordo_soins_medicament table.

How the add a Ordo_soins_medicament object only if not null

Thanks

Comment: So you have a relationship where one side is `ManyToMany` and the other side is `ManyToOne`? That should be consistent, choose one type. You can also remove the `cascade` action from the `ManyToMany` for now.

Comment: I take now only the ManyToMany. same problem. without the persist i get an error (A new entity was found through the relationship 'CoordinBundle\Entity\Ordo_soins_perfusion#medoc' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity)

Comment: You have a  new line in ordo_soins_medicament? and what is in it? and what's in the join table? I don't understand what ordo_soins_medicament it created, since you didn't send any value in the form. Also, can you post the other side of the relation please?

Comment: i have only the attributes of the ordo_soins_medicament enity, no relationship with other entity. in the join table it save the ids of the two entities to make the relation ManyToMany, and in the ordo_soins_medicament it save only the id with null value of the others attributes. its automatically because of the persist in the ManyToMany relation

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the `ManyToMany` relationship is correct. Thereafter initialize an empty `new ArrayCollection()` on these properties, so relationships actually can be added by Doctrine.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->medoc = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

The next step is to make sure the relationship is set properly, by adding getters/setters. In case of collections you could also use `add`.

```
public function addMedoc($item)
{
    $item->setPerfusion($this);
    $this->medoc->add($item);
}
```

Doctrine will handle the relationship/join table when you persist and flush the new entity.

Comment: Hello, my problem is not to add an object. when  i want to add it work perfectly. But my problem is: I want to save only the Ordo_soins_perfusion object if the Ordo_soins_medicament is null (let the form empty) in my form, Ordo_soins_perfusion has a collection of  Ordo_soins_medicament.  i think because of the persist in the MantToMany it perform a save of the second object even if i dont fill the form